# Visual Studio 2013 Can't save, build, or rebuild solution

Tags: visual-studio

Suddenly after i clicked clean solution i am no longer able either to save, build or do anything to the solution. It appears to be a bug as every time i hit CTRL+S or just Rebuild or Build or even Start button i get this message

[image]

- Also i double checked all the assemblies and they are there nothing
  is missing. I need to find a solution without losing my unsaved data.

Comment: most likely your installation has corrupted or your AV is kicking in. if I were you, I would try with a brand new clean solution and project and see if you can build that without code. For your current project and solution, save it and back it up. If it still fails, then uninstall CLEANLY and then reinstall VS

Comment: @Ahmedilyas : isn't it clear that i can't save my data ? i can't close VS without saving the hell out of the data.

Comment: you could easily copy and paste the code in notepad or go on disk to the folder where the project is and back that up :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well this is strange glitch which I once faced with Visual Studio which results in losing the linkage to it's references or something like that.

A quick fix would be just

1. Opening the project in a 2nd visual studio instance (without
   closing the existing one to keep your data alive!)
2. Rebuild your project from the newly opened 2nd instance then close
   and return to your bugged visual studio (1st instance) and it should
   work be able to save/build/rebuild now.
3. When switching back to your 1st instance, if you had made changes
   in the 2nd instance to get your project to compile, the 1st instance
   will detect these and ask if you would like to reload the changed
   files. Select "No to all" otherwise you will lose your unsaved
   changes in the 1st instance.

Comment: This answer exemplifies the best of one type of Stack Overflow answer. A simple, effective 'just do it' bandaid to a real WTF issue with a tool. 
I really don't care why VS/VB gets bolixed this way -- stuff happens. I just needed a way out of the rat hole and you guys gave and saved me hours of work. Thank you!
I guess I should mention, FWIW, this fix worked for me with VS 2015 Community Edition.

Comment: I wish I could keep upvoting this answer and question.  Just ran into this bug for the second time, it still exists in VS2017.

Answer (score -4):

Clearly, your project is referencing something that doesn't exist, something that seems to be called 'Project'.

SUGGESTIONS:

1) Look at your project in the MSVS Solution Explorer.
   Then look at your .sln and .csproj files in Notepad (or your favorite text editor).
   See if you can figure out what "Project" is missing (or corrupted) and try to fix it.

2) See if you can go back to a "known good" backup of your project, and try rebuilding that.

3) Failing all else, start from scratch with a brand new project, and manually "Add" the source and resources to recreate your corrupted project.

4) Also look at these links:

- [Could not load file or assembly](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb7fa760-0094-4e8a-ac02-22a171c2a681/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftvisualstudioqualitytoolsunittestframework?forum=vsautotest)
- [Could not load file or assembly in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467049/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-in-visual-studio-2012-c-sharp)

PS:
If you've made a bunch of changes since your last "Save", then:

5) See if "File, Save" works on a file-by-file basis

... OR ...

6) If you can't save *ANYTHING* ...
   then kiss your changes goodbye...
   and remember to save more often the next time ;)